# Ruby on Rails Postgres/Active Record Search Optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql

So it's possible that there may not be a way to fix this but I thought I would ask:

I have a Postgresql DB set up. The first table contains replays which each have 10 unique players (a has many relationship). I want to render a JSON based on my search that contains the replays with their players. However, I am pulling a large number of replays (2000) -- which all have 10 players, meaning searching for 20,000 players.

This what the index search currently looks like:

```
def index
  @replays = Replay.where(map_id: params['map_id'].to_i)
  @replays = @replays.reverse
  render json: @replays[0..2000].to_json(include: [:players])
end
```

The search takes this long:

```
Completed 200 OK in 639596ms (Views: 42.1ms | ActiveRecord: 329252.3ms)
```

Is there a better way I can search and render the JSON that won't take this long? It's worth noting that just searching for 2k replays, 20k players, or even a single specific replay with players takes only a couple seconds (the first search itself also takes only a couple of seconds) so I assume it's a volume issue.

Comment: can you post the actual sql query that is generated?

Comment: The first search:

    SELECT "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."replay_id" = $1

Then when searching the players: 
    SELECT "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."replay_id" = $1  [["replay_id", 117217]]

(per replay)

Answer (score 2):

Try to eager load your replays

```
replays = Replay.last_two_thousands_by_map_id(params[:map_id])

render json: replays.to_json(include: [:players])

# replay.rb model
def self.last_two_thousands_by_map_id(map_id)
  includes(:players).where(map_id: map_id).order(id: :desc).limit(2000)
end
```

Comment: This works, the time was cut drastically.

    Completed 200 OK in 254032ms (Views: 34.1ms | ActiveRecord: 20682.4ms)

Comment: Just the ticket - nice answer. I'd add that it'd be worth dropping at least some elements of that request into a model scope to clean up the controller a little. @GustavMauler - for future reference, it was an N + 1 problem slowing you down, [docs here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

Comment: the query still seems pretty huge. Open another question with the new bottleneck if you want. Thanks @SRack

Comment: Yeah I see that now.

Perhaps it's greedy but is it possible to get even better performance?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure. But we need more info as the ones in this question. Open another one

Comment: Will when I can (can only post every 90 minutes...?)